# Terraform state locking using DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

Our Terraform layout is such that we run Terraform for many aws (100+) accounts, and save Terraform state file remotely to a central S3 bucket.

The new locking feature sounds useful and wish to implement it but I am unsure if I can make use of a central DynamoDB table in the same account as that of our S3 bucket or do I need to create a DynamoDB table in each of the AWS accounts?

Answer (score 21):

You can use a single DynamoDB table to control the locking for the state file for all of the accounts. This would work even if you had multiple S3 buckets to store state in.

The DynamoDB table is keyed on [`LockID` which is set as a bucketName/path](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/df1fc8f2c3c74c4e992a7f9690680be139bf5b0e/backend/remote-state/s3/client.go#L130). So as long as you have a unique combination of those you will be fine (you should or you have bigger problems with your state management).

Obviously you will need to set up cross account IAM policies to allow users creating things in one account to be able to manage items in DynamoDB.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and feedback soon.

Comment: Any feedback on this?

Comment: Yep, tried and it worked just fine for me. I set up the table manually then had terraform connect to it through the .tf file. Note: I used the other answer by Jirawat as a syntax example (under Usage Example). Also, I am using terraform 0.9.7, so I had to use lock_table instead of dynamodb_table which is used for later versions.

Comment: Could you use the same DynamDB for multiple terraform state files?

Comment: Dimitris Moraitidis, I think ydaetskcoR has answered that already. It's possible to use a single dynamodb table for locking state across multiple state files.

Comment: Not sure I get how this works, does this mean we just set a different hash_key for each module/lock, or a different attribute "name", or both?

Comment: Or do we leave the hash_key = "LockID" and attribute { name = "LockID" }, and it automatically stores a unique lock based on the backend "s3" {} block's "bucket" and "key" values? Just not sure if I should be messing with those LockID values.

Comment: Seems like it's the latter, just make sure the bucket name is unique and the LockID strings can stay the same... if this is wrong someone please correct me.

Comment: Or actually the "key" part of the backend config needs to be unique, rather... :/

Answer (score 17):

To use terraform DynamoDB locking, follow the steps below

1.Create an AWS DynamoDB with terraform to lock the terraform.tfstate.

```
provider "aws" {
   region = "us-east-2"
}


resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb-terraform-lock" {
   name = "terraform-lock"
   hash_key = "LockID"
   read_capacity = 20
   write_capacity = 20

   attribute {
      name = "LockID"
      type = "S"
   }

   tags {
     Name = "Terraform Lock Table"
   }
}
```

2.Execute terraform to create the DynamoDB table on AWS

*terraform apply*

**Usage Example**

1.Use the DynamoDB table to lock terraform.state creation on AWS. As an EC2 example

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-s3-tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"
    key = "ec2-example/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
    encrypt = true
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2-example" {
  ami = "ami-a4c7edb2"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"    
}
```

The dynamodb_table value must match the name of the DynamoDB table we created.

2.Initialize the terraform S3 and DynamoDB backend

*terraform init*

3.Execute terraform to create EC2 server

*terraform apply*

To see the code, go to the
[Github DynamoDB Locking Example](https://github.com/juttayaya/devops/tree/master/hashicorp/terraform/s3-tfstate-example)

Comment: Should we set `kms_key_id` as well, if you enable `encrypt = true`?

Comment: This answer does not address whether a DynamoDB table can be shared or not.

Answer (score 0):

For those who needs a **local/self-managed version of DynamoDB**, you can find the opensourced binary from AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html)

for example deploying DynamoDB using docker-compose:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
 dynamodb-local:
   command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data"
   image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
   container_name: dynamodb-local
   ports:
     - "8000:8000"
   volumes:
     - "./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data"
   working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
```

you can then use the same code as **@jirawat** mentioned

```
    terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "terraform-s3-tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"
    key = "ec2-example/terraform.tfstate"
    dynamodb_table = "terraform-lock"
    encrypt = false
    dynamodb_endpoint="YOUR_DYNAMODB_ENDPOINT"

  }
}
```

> Don't forget to create terraform-lock before your first usage
> [image]